# Suppressing variable name length from protocols in frameworks

Tags: ios, swiftlint

We are using Ad frameworks in our iOS application and integrated SwiftLint as part of the code. We noticed that some protocols from the Ad framework have variable length 2. Example is:

```
func ad(_ ad: Any!, requestFailedWithError error: Error!)
```

As variable length is 2, SwiftLint is throwing warnings. How can I suppress these warnings in yml file? Or is there any better way to handle these warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to disable the warning each times you implement the method:

```
// swiftlint:disable:next variable_name
func ad(_ ad: Any!, requestFailedWithError error: Error!)
```

If you disable the rule inside the yml config file you'll disable it for your whole project and you should not do that.

Comment: you can add an iml config file in a specific folder only

Comment: I didn't know that. It could be a solution depending on its project architecture.

Comment: @CZ54, Its not associated with a folder. Protocol methods when implemented in our code will have the function param limitation in our src code. I think what ever Yannick Loriot suggested is good one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `.swiftlint.yml` in project root folder and add configuration for folder exclusion there. Example:

```
excluded: 
  - Pods
  - RentalProjectUITests
```

More can be found here: https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#configuration